# How to replace text in a PDF using python

Tags: python, nlp

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

replacements = [
    ("old string", "new string")
]

pdf = PdfFileReader(open(r'C:\Users\DELL-PC\Desktop\text augmentation.pdf', "rb"))
writer = PdfFileWriter() 

for page in pdf.pages:
    contents = page.getContents().getData()
    for (a,b) in replacements:
        contents = contents.replace(a.encode('utf-8'), b.encode('utf-8'))
    page.getContents().setData(contents)
    writer.addPage(page)
    
with open("modified.pdf", "wb") as f:
     writer.write(f)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`pypdf` (and also PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4) cannot do that.